# Use Desktop Duplication API to capture Logon & Lock Screens

Tags: windows, winapi, remote-desktop, vnc, dxgi

Since Windows 10 doesn't support Mirror drivers, how do I use Desktop Duplication API to capture console at all times i.e. start with logon window, then user's desktop (after the user logs in) and also the lock screen?

Answer (score 2):

Detect desktop Switch event then `SetThreadDesktop` on the thread that is capturing and make sure you're running as `SYSTEM` user.